# Notice: Undefined index: video_code in C:\xampp\htdocs\home_teacher_upload.php on line 12

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

Hi so I keep running into this error and I was wondering how can I fix it! It is very important because this project is for a school degree.

This form basically will be used for uploading youtube embed codes and call them in another page!
I am using strip_tags but it seems it will not work because it says undefined variables both $video_title and $video_code.So this is what the page looks like when i first open it:https://i.stack.imgur.com/EP63e.jpg
and this is when i click the submit button:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/kz4ft.jpg 
I know its a duplicate but I have tried so many options found here but none seems to work!I tried isset(); , I tried $_POST[] but no better results.I also tried to change the whole registration and login form but still nothing!
What are those errors and why
I am new into PHP so sorry for the bad explanation!

This is the home_teacher_upload.php :

```
<?php

require_once("session.php");
require_once("class.user.php");

$teacher = new USER();

if(isset($_POST['btn-submit']))
{
   $video_title = strip_tags($_GET['video_title']);
   $video_code = strip_tags($_GET['video_code']);

  if ($video_title == "") {
    $error[]="Duhet të vendosni titullin fillimisht!";
  }
    echo "<h3>Videoja u ngarkua me sukses!</h3>";
  }
   try {
        $stmt = $teacher->runQuery("SELECT video_title, video_code FROM videos WHERE video_title=:video_title OR video_code=:video_code");
      $stmt->execute(array(':video_title'=>$video_title, ':video_code'=>$video_code));
      $row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

      if($row['video_title']==$video_title) {
        echo "<h3>Ky titull është jo valid!</h3>";
      }
      else if($row['video_code']==$video_code) {
        $error[] = "Kjo video aktualisht është e ngarkuar";
      }
      else
      {
        $teacher->submit_video($video_title,$video_code);  
               }
      } 

      catch (PDOException $e) {

          echo $e->getMessage();   

      }





?>
<link href="img/favicon.png" rel="shortcut icon" />
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cookie">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/user.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/fonts/font-awesome.min.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fjalla+One" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Patua+One" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bree+Serif" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Anton" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Hammersmith+One" rel="stylesheet">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<link href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.3-jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css"  />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/user.css">
<title>Ngarkoni video!</title>
</head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" style="
          font-family: Bree Serif;">IB-Learning </a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="profile.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>&nbsp;Profili</a></li>
                <li><a href="logout.php?logout=true"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span>&nbsp;Dilni</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </nav>


    <div class="clearfix"></div>

<div class="container-fluid" style="margin-top:80px;">


</div>
<div class="wanna" style="text-align: center;">
<h3 style="font-family: Hammersmith One;">Ngarkoni një video</h3></div>
<div class="form" style="text-align: center;     margin-left: 431px;
    padding-top: 13px;">
<form class="submit_video" method="POST" style="text-align: center;">

  <div class="form-group" style="font-family: Bree Serif; width: 28%;">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="video_title" required placeholder="Titulli i videos" style="text-align: center;"/>
        </div>

  <div class="form-group" style="font-family: Bree Serif;margin-left: -37px;">
            <textarea name="video_code" class="form-control" style="width: 240px; margin: 0px 337px 0px 0px; height: 165px; text-align: center;" form="code" placeholder="Embed code i videos" required="true"></textarea>
        </div>

<div class="button_form-group">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-right: 415px;font-family: Bree Serif;" name="btn-submit">
                  Submit
                </button>
            </div>
</form>
</div>



<?php include('footer.php');?>
<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
  h3{
    font-family: Bree Serif;
    text-align: center;
    padding-left: 20px;
  }
</style>
</body>
</html>
```

This is session.php :

```
<?php

    session_start();

    require_once 'class.user.php';
    $session = new USER();

    // if user session is not active(not loggedin) this page will help 'home.php and profile.php' to redirect to login page
    // put this file within secured pages that users (users can't access without login)

    if(!$session->is_loggedin())
    {
        // session no set redirects to login page
        $session->redirect('login.php');
    }
```

and this is class.user.php :

```
<?php

require_once('dbconfig.php');

class USER
{   

    private $conn;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $database = new Database();
        $db = $database->dbConnection();
        $this->conn = $db;
    }

    public function runQuery($sql)
    {
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
        return $stmt;
    }


    public function register($uname,$umail,$upass)
    {
        try
        {
            $new_password = password_hash($upass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

            $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO tik_students(user_name,user_email,user_pass) 
                                                       VALUES(:uname, :umail, :upass)");

            $stmt->bindparam(":uname", $uname);
            $stmt->bindparam(":umail", $umail);
            $stmt->bindparam(":upass", $new_password);

            $stmt->execute();   

            return $stmt;   
        }
        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }               
    }
    public function register_teacher($t_uname,$t_umail,$t_upass)
    {
        try
        {
            $new_password = password_hash($upass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

            $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO tik_teachers(user_name,user_email,user_pass)
                                                       VALUES(:uname, :umail, :upass)");

            $stmt->bindparam(":uname", $t_uname);
            $stmt->bindparam(":umail", $t_umail);
            $stmt->bindparam(":upass", $t_new_password);                              

            $stmt->execute();   

            return $stmt;   
        }
        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }               
    }

    public function doLogin($uname,$umail,$upass)
    {
        try
        {
            $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT user_id, user_name, user_email, user_pass FROM tik_students WHERE user_name=:uname OR user_email=:umail ");
            $stmt->execute(array(':uname'=>$uname, ':umail'=>$umail));
            $userRow=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            if($stmt->rowCount() == 1)
            {
                if(password_verify($upass, $userRow['user_pass']))
                {
                    $_SESSION['user_session'] = $userRow['user_id'];
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

    public function doLogin_teacher($t_uname,$t_umail,$t_upass)
    {
        try
        {
            $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT user_id, user_name, user_email, user_pass FROM tik_teachers WHERE user_name=:uname OR user_email=:umail ");
            $stmt->execute(array(':uname'=>$t_uname, ':umail'=>$t_umail));
            $userRow=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            if($stmt->rowCount() == 1)
            {
                if(password_verify($t_upass, $userRow['user_pass']))
                {
                    $_SESSION['user_session'] = $userRow['user_id'];
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

        public function submit_video($video_title,$video_code)
    {
        try
        {

            $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO videos(video_title, video_code) 
                                                       VALUES(:video_title, :video_code)");

            $stmt->bindparam(":video_title", $video_title);
            $stmt->bindparam(":video_code", $video_code);       

            $stmt->execute();   

            return $stmt;   
        }
        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }               
    }


    public function is_t_loggedin()
    {
        if(isset($_SESSION['user_session']))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }


    public function is_loggedin()
    {
        if(isset($_SESSION['user_session']))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    public function redirect($url)
    {
        header("Location: $url");
    }

    public function doLogout()
    {
        session_destroy();
        unset($_SESSION['user_session']);
        return true;
    }
}

?>
```

Help would be appreciated

Comment: I did see that too and tried the options there but they didn't work!

Comment: What's the URL you're receiving on *home_teacher_upload.php* page?

Comment: The url????????

Comment: @AvniBeka URL is [Uniform Resource Locator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator). See the URL or use `var_dump($_GET);` to check what you're getting in `$_GET` superglobal.

Comment: It says array = 0;

Answer (score 1):

> **Notice: Undefined index / Undefined offset**
>
> This notice appears when you (or PHP) try to access an undefined index
>   of an array.

You need to check like below first

```
if(isset($_GET['video_code'])){

}
```

So in your case

```
$video_code = isset($_GET['video_code']) ? strip_tags($_GET['video_code']): ' ';
```

Check if the index exists before you access it.

For this you can use

[`isset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)

or

[`array_key_exists()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php):

```
//isset()
$video_code = isset($_GET['video_code']) ? strip_tags($_GET['video_code']): '';

// OR

//array_key_exists()
$video_code = array_key_exists('video_code',$_GET) ? strip_tags($_GET['video_code']): '';
```

Comment: I dont understand how to do that!

Comment: So in 'my_index' i should put the name of the variable?

Comment: @AvniBeka no thats just example, see above update

Comment: Yeah so my actual code is strip_tags($_POST['video_title']);I should go with the code you wrote up there and replace my_index with video_title

Comment: The basic thing you need to understand here is you are trying to access the array element whose index is not defined, that is why we are validating first with isset() function

Comment: Sorry sir but i don't really understand it that well!